# Can a subclass of UIImageView respond to touch events?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I know others asked similar questions but I checked and their problems isn't the same as mine.

Here is the code from the customImageView

```
@implementation KeysTest

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self.userInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
 self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whitekey.gif"];
}
return self;
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"test!");
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't recognize the userInteractionEnabled  method. Also, the codeSense feature didn't work for the touchesBegan method.

Comment: May be a typo but line 6 should be self.userInteractionEnabled = YES or [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that your code sample would compile correctly. But commenter Sam is correct, `[self.userInteractionEnabled:YES]` is not a proper function. This needs to be changed to

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```